# How does subplot work and what is the difference between subplot(121) and subplot(1,2,1) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am a bit unclear with how `subplot` works.  Specifically, what is the difference between `subplot(121)` and `subplot(1,2,1)` in MATLAB?  I have tried to search the `subplot` documentation, but I can't seem to find what I am looking for.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Long story short, there is no difference.  How `subplot` works is the following:

```
subplot(m,n,p); %//or
subplot(mnp);
```

You have three numbers that are used within `subplot`.  `subplot` places multiple **figures** within the same window.  You can place plots within a `m x n` grid, where `m` contains the number of rows and `n` contains the number of columns in your figure.  `p` determines **where** you want to place your plot within the grid.  The number `p` increases from `1` up to `m x n`, and the plots are placed from left to right, and top to bottom.

In this case, when you do `subplot(1,2,1);` or `subplot(121);`, you would like to have **one** row and **two** columns worth of figures.  The last number, `p=1` means that you wish to place the plot in the **left** most column.  When you do `subplot(1,2,2);` or `subplot(122);`, this is when `p=2` and you wish to place the plot in the **right** most column.

How you use `subplot` is in the following fashion:

1. Determine **how many** rows and columns of plots you want within this window first (i.e. `m` and `n`).
2. Spawn a blank `figure` window
3. For each plot you want to create...

   - Call `subplot` and choose the right location(s) of where you want the plot to appear.
   - Write the necessary code to create your plot like you would for just a plot occupying a **single window**.
   - Plot your data
4. Repeat Step #3 for each plot we have until we run out of `subplot` slots.

Here is an illustrative example.  Let's create a window that has **two** rows and **three** columns worth of figures within the same window.  As such:

```
figure;
rng(10); %// Set seed for reproducibility
subplot(2,3,1);
x = rand(100,1);
y = rand(100,1);
plot(x,y,'b.');
title('First plot');
subplot(2,3,2);
x = rand(100,1);
y = rand(100,1);
plot(x,y,'b.');
title('Second plot');
subplot(2,3,3);
x = rand(100,1);
y = rand(100,1);
plot(x,y,'b.');
title('Third plot');
subplot(2,3,4);
x = rand(100,1);
y = rand(100,1);
plot(x,y,'b.');
title('Fourth plot');
subplot(2,3,5);
x = rand(100,1);
y = rand(100,1);
plot(x,y,'b.');
title('Fifth plot');
subplot(2,3,6);
x = rand(100,1);
y = rand(100,1);
plot(x,y,'b.');
title('Sixth plot');
```

What the above code does is that we generate random sets of points that are `100 x 1` each for pairs of `x` and `y` and we plot them in multiple locations within the overall window.  Notice that the last parameter of `subplot` increases linearly, while the first two parameters **stay the same**.  You **must** make sure that you **know** how many figures you want within the overall window **before** you start plotting.  The figure that the code above describes looks like the following:

[image]

You can also specify **a vector** of points for `p`.  However, should you do it this way, you **must** call `subplot` this way: `subplot(m,n,p);`.  If `p` is a *single number*, then either `subplot(m,n,p);` or `subplot(mnp)` will work.

If you specify `p` to be a *vector*, what this will do is that one plot you make **will occupy multiple** spaces / slots within the same figure window.  As an example, if you did: `subplot(2,3,1:3);`, this will take one plot and **occupy the entire first row of your figure**.  You can then issue more plots in slots 4, 5 and 6.  In other words:

```
figure;
rng(10); %// Set seed for reproducibility
subplot(2,3,1:3);
x = rand(100,1);
y = rand(100,1);
plot(x,y,'b.');
title('First plot');
subplot(2,3,4:5);
x = rand(100,1);
y = rand(100,1);
plot(x,y,'b.');
title('Second plot');
subplot(2,3,6);
x = rand(100,1);
y = rand(100,1);
plot(x,y,'b.');
title('Third plot');
```

The figure looks like:

[image]

As you can see, we have occupied the **first row** using `subplot(2,3,1:3);` with the first plot.  The second plot occupies slots `p=4,p=5` using `subplot(2,3,4:5);`.  This occupies the second row, and first and second columns.  Finally our last plot occupies the second row, third column using `subplot(2,3,6);`.  Remember, the slots go from left to right and top to bottom, and `p` can not only be a single number but a vector as well.  If you wanted to occupy the **first two rows and two columns**, you would do `subplot(2,3,[1 2 4 5]);`  Now, if you wanted to occupy the entire right most column, you can do `subplot(2,3,[3 6]);`, or if you just want the top most location in the right most column, you can do `subplot(2,3,3);` or `subplot(233);`, then if you want to tackle the last location in the last column and at the bottom right, you can do `subplot(2,3,6);` or `subplot(236);`

One final thing that I want to make sure that you remember is that you need to make sure you call `subplot` **before** you decide to show your plot.  Once you're finished, switch over to the next slot and keep working.

Hope this helps!  Good luck!

Comment: +1 Wow. *Great* elaborated answer; great use of images.

Comment: @AndrewJanke - Thank you very much :)  Coming from a SO MATLAB veteran, that means a lot.  I am standing on the shoulder of MATLAB giants here!

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you so much!! Really helped!! However , I understand 95% of what you wrote, because in subplot document, "subplot(111) is an exception to the rules above, and is not identical in behavior to subplot(1,1,1).  For reasons of backwards compatibility, it is a special case of subplot which does not immediately create an axes,,,(since too long, you could read it in MATLAB 'help subplot'.  I can't understand what it means,, T_T;; maybe a little difference.. I want an example. ^^;

Comment: @user3595632 - You're welcome.  If I have helped you in any way, consider accepting my answer.  Click on the checkmark icon at the top left of my post underneath the up and down arrows.

Comment: *create an axes* means that when you call `subplot`, it creates a **blank** plot window with default axes that has nothing in it.  However, that is something you don't have to worry about because you **will** place something eventually within each slot when you're calling `subplot`.  This is honestly a technicality that you **don't need to worry about**.  You only need to be concerned with **where** your plot is going to be placed by calling `subplot` correctly.  After, you place your plot which will replace that default blank plot anyway.  It's something you shouldn't be concerned with.

Comment: Thanks ^^. I really appreciate it

Comment: The "multiple slots" usage is quite cool. Not often used.  +1