# How can I put a smaller figure right next to a larger figure using subplot (or some other way)?

Tags: matlab

Here's an example of such an arrangement (where the smaller figure is to the right of the larger figure).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the first subplot is about 3 times as wide as the second, you can do it like this:

```
subplot(1, 4, 1 : 3)
% generate first plot

subplot(1, 4, 4)
% generate second plot
```

The trick is that one subplot can be composed of any rectangular collection of grid cells:

```
******************* *******
*     |     |     * *     *
*  1  |  2  |  3  * *  4  *
*     |     |     * *     *
******************* *******
```

For more information, see [Subplots with Different Sizes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html#btw1_6e-1) in the documentation of `subplot`.

Comment: Also take a look at my post on `subplot` here.  It shows you how it works and you can basically fit graphs of both equal and unequal sizes in the same figure window: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337813/what-is-difference-between-subplot121-and-subplot1-2-1-in-matlab

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this with `subplot`, which I think by definition uses a regular grid. What you'll want to do to achieve this effect is to create a second axis in your figure, which you can do easily through the GUI, and then switch back and forth between the two axes to configure each plot and the way the axes look.

Some potentially helpful references:

[Axes (to add new axis)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html)

[Subplot only creates a grid](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html)