# Designing bandstop filter for positive and negative frequencies with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, wav, noise-reduction

I have two WAV files of the same sound recording, but one contains background noise and the other does not. I am trying to use a **bandstop filter** to filter the one that contains background noise.

I have found the **fft** of both signals and graphed them. I have determined two symmetric areas (one with positive frequencies and one with negative frequencies) on the graph of the noisy signal that should be filtered out. The **bandstop filter** does not use negative frequencies, so I am wondering how I can possibly filter both of these areas out.

Also, how do I find what frequencies these areas on my graphs are?

Comment: Please show us actual code.  It's much more effective than describing what you've done.

Comment: As far as I know, any filter with real coefficients operates on the positive and the so-called "negative" frequencies. Otherwise, you would get a complex signal.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for the reply. I'm sorry for the late response, but I will attach the code and some images in the next comment. I am still relatively new to signal processing, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @rayryeng I have included the graphs of both ffts in the link here: background noise: [link](http://imgur.com/Qk2obYd,FUZ8Myd#0) regular: [link](http://imgur.com/Qk2obYd,FUZ8Myd#1) I actually used the code you provided in this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195089/remove-noise-from-wav-file-matlab) to do this and to help write the code, so thank you. I am trying to design a bandstop filter by using : `[b,a] = butter(n, [beginFreq, endFreq], 'stop')` and `fOut = filter(b, a, f)`

Comment: @rayryeng  I am having trouble figuring out which unwanted frequencies I need to filter out of the noisy signal/how to code for these frequencies. Any thoughts/suggestions? Do you think my code will work? I am not sure if those few modifications will work correctly. Thanks for any input you might have.